# iphone game light effects with cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, quartz-graphics

I am learning cocos2d for iPhone and came across [Munch Time](http://www.facebook.com/munchtimegame?sk=wall&filter=12) (see also the company website [page](http://www.gamistrygames.com/main/munchtime)), notably game of the week this week :). I am an indie developer, so won't be able to achieve the same great quality, but would like to understand how they managed to do the light effect of the moon and start that can be viewed in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iSpYC3IPAY).

What do you think? I am planning to stick with cocos2d 1.x as it is compatible with a wider range of iPhones rather than cocos2d 2.x unless using the latter is the only way to get those effects (or unless you reckon that achieving the quality of Munch time is not possible with Cocos2d).

Thanks for reading..

Comment: I wouldn't doubt that Munch time was written in Cocos2d.  Cocos comes with 2 different physics engines that are easy to use.

Comment: Thank you :). What about the light effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the stable release on Cocos2d which is 1.0.1 as of this post.

The lighting effects you are referring to are likely done with the images.  The moon is solid, but has alpha fade on the 'light' around it, meaning it starts mostly white near the edge of the moon, but fades in transparency as it gets away from the moon edge to give the glow effect.

The clouds also look to be transparent somewhat, to allow the moonlight to slightly seep through.

However, all the animations, effects, etc, should all be reproducible in Cocos2d.

Comment: I actually found also this good book [link] (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj4ts5KRSTs&context=C3d72584ADOEgsToPDskIYS7jh8tfXtA5H6wQq3j1Y) which seems to answer most of my questions :).. I have just ordered it. Thanks :)

Comment: I highly recommend "Learning Cocos2d" by Addison Wesley. The one you showed has a lot of "Recipes" but doesn't explain what's happening very well.  The Addison Wesley book by Strough and Wenderlich is the best book out there currently.  Well worth the purchase price.  Plus, Ray Wenderlich is very active in his website in case you have questions or problems.